# Change the monospace font used by Gmail

Tags: gmail, font

When I get a mail in Gmail and somebody has used plain text, it shows me in the Courier New font which is default on Windows. I changed the monospace font in Chrome's settings to Consolas but Gmail doesn't honor that. Any ideas on how to change from Courier New to Consolas for plain text emails?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the Stylish browser extension.
2. Click the Stylish icon and go to "Manage Styles"
3. Add this style.  It will configure Gmail to use a fixed-width font for plaintext messages:

   ```
   @namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
   @-moz-document domain("mail.google.com") {
     /* change the font family and font size of body message */
     div[class="a3s aXjCH"] {
      font-family: DejaVu Sans Mono, Liberation Mono, Luxi Mono, courier, arial, sans-serif !important;
     }
   }
   ```

This is adapted from my first answer posted here: http://dannyman.toldme.com/2007/03/08/gmail-fixed-width/ ... which I will now update.

Alternatively, there are several (similar?) styles available within Stylish already: https://userstyles.org/styles/browse?search_terms=gmail+monospace

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you actually *did* change the default Monospace font. Google Chrome refreshes my font changes immediately, in monospace and in regular font, so changes should show up in browser.

Your user profile may also be corrupted - [see my answer for a guide on how to create a new profile.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57812/why-do-i-have-html-tags-in-my-google-search-results/57814#57814)

Comment: Yes, I have checked. On other sites where monospace is used, Chrome shows Consolas only. Only in Gmail, this is happening

Comment: @pratnala Huh. That is *very* strange. I'm honestly stumped now - maybe try clearing your cookies and your cache?

Comment: I'll try and let you know.